# Create pandas timezone-aware datetimeindex on already local timezone

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to read in a file that is in US/Eastern time into a dataframe with the time as an index.  Given that 11/02/2008 is a DST switch day, there are two hour 1s (the order indicates which hour is daylight vs. standard).  When trying to localize, the code fails as these are ambiguous.  Now the pytz module has a way to indicate whether a date is dst or not which would be useful here, but it is not clear if that is exposed by pandas.  One solution would be to create date_parser function for read_csv, but is there any way using other pandas functions to achieve the localized DatetimeIndex?  Thanks.

```
from pandas import read_csv, DatetimeIndex
from StringIO import StringIO

test = 'Time,Number\n\
11/02/2008 00:00, 1\n\
11/02/2008 01:00, 2\n\
11/02/2008 01:00, 3\n\
11/02/2008 02:00, 4\n\
11/02/2008 03:00, 5\n\
11/02/2008 04:00, 6\n'

df = read_csv(StringIO(test), parse_dates=[0]) #read in the csv
di = DatetimeIndex(df['Time']) # create a datetime index
di.tz_localize('US/Eastern') # try to localize to current timezone
File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/index.py", line 1463, in tz_localize
new_dates = tslib.tz_localize_to_utc(self.asi8, tz)
File "tslib.pyx", line 1561, in pandas.tslib.tz_localize_to_utc (pandas/tslib.c:24350)
AmbiguousTimeError: 2008-11-02 01:00:00
```

The desired output is:

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2008-11-02 00:00:00, ..., 2008-11-02 04:00:00]
Length: 6, Freq: H, Timezone: US/Eastern
dr.values
array(['2008-11-02T00:00:00.000000000-0400',
   '2008-11-02T01:00:00.000000000-0400',
   '2008-11-02T01:00:00.000000000-0500',
   '2008-11-02T02:00:00.000000000-0500',
   '2008-11-02T03:00:00.000000000-0500',
   '2008-11-02T04:00:00.000000000-0500'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this. The index is not in any timezone initially, so need to say, hey you are 'UTC', then you can localize properly.

```
In [24]: x = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Time']).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')

In [25]: x
Out[25]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2008-11-01 20:00:00, ..., 2008-11-02 00:00:00]
Length: 6, Freq: None, Timezone: US/Eastern

In [26]: x.values
Out[26]: 
array(['2008-11-01T20:00:00.000000000-0400',
       '2008-11-01T21:00:00.000000000-0400',
       '2008-11-01T21:00:00.000000000-0400',
       '2008-11-01T22:00:00.000000000-0400',
       '2008-11-01T23:00:00.000000000-0400',
       '2008-11-02T00:00:00.000000000-0400'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```